# Meta templating with rails and angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, macros, lisp, template-meta-programming

I've never heard of this term, "meta-templating" however, the word is intriguing. I want to understand a practical use case for meta-templating. Also, get some example code, in hopes to implement meta-templating myself.

This seed has been planted, after watching [Youtube:  Using AngularJS with Rails - NYC Meetup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UjYIVwGbNC4#t=839).  He also mentioned Lisp Macros and how very similar they were?  A better explanation between lisp macros, rails/angular and meta templating, would be most appreciated.